# Showing sharepoint web part in windows 8 app

Tags: c#, sharepoint, windows-8, microsoft-metro, web-parts

I want to show SharePoint web part on windows 8 app . how can I do that ?

Comment: is your question "how to use Web Browser in Windows 8 app?"

Comment: I don't have experience with SharePoint. At this point I have tried anything . don't know where to start.

Comment: No I am not trying to show web browser in windows app

Answer (score 1):

I am giving you few links, that I found while my research of WinRT and Sharepoint integration.

[Windows 8 applications and SharePoint Online: Connecting the two (a programmer view)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bardak/archive/2012/10/26/windows-8-applications-and-sharepoint-online-connecting-the-two-a-programmer-view.aspx)

[Sharepoint WinRT Client](https://sharepointwinrt.codeplex.com/)

[Windows 8 App For SharePoint Online](https://win8app4sponline.codeplex.com/)

[Developing Windows 8 Store Apps for SharePoint Online with SSO (Single Sign On)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/omarv/archive/2012/11/15/developing-windows-store-apps-for-sharepoint-online-with-sso-single-sign-on.aspx)

[Create a SharePoint Lists reader (Windows Store apps using C# and XAML)](http://havivi.blogspot.in/2012/09/create-sharepoint-lists-reader-windows.html)

[SharePoint 2013 Search REST API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nadeemis/archive/2012/08/24/sharepoint-2013-search-rest-api.aspx)

[Developing Windows 8 (Metro Style) Applications for SharePoint](http://blog.sharedove.com/adisjugo/index.php/2011/11/02/developing-windows-8-metro-style-applications-for-sharepoint/)